# Не работает Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android

Почему не обновляется страница и swipe начинает работать с любого положения прокрутки, а не в самом верху.

xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView">
</WebView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

java

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.blue_swipe, R.color.green_swipe,
            R.color.orange_swipe, R.color.red_swipe);
}
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // stop refresh
            mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Страница не обновляется т.к. вы её не обновляете. В методе onRefresh вам надо собственно и запустить обновление, а не только остановить анимацию загрузки через 3с.

Проблему же с появлением индикатора загрузки в любом месте попробуйте решить через проставление для WebView высоты по содержимому и обернув последний в NestedScrollView

Comment: Нужно onCreate поставить в onRefresh пробовал так были ошибки

Comment: @steep, попробуйте переформулировать - я не понял что вы хотите сказать

Comment: Как запустить обновление в onRefresh?

Comment: @steep, просто ещё раз вызовите `webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");`

Comment: куда бы я его не вставил везде ошибка

Comment: @steep, пока вы будете скрывать что за ошибка - помочь вам будет сложно. Скорее всего у вас просто переменная в нужном месте не объявлена. Попробуйте её объявить на уровне клааса, а не метода.

Comment: Нужно было вместе с этим вставить `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` метод тыка работает.

Comment: На счёт высоты по содержимому можно подробней,

Comment: Ой, а как сделать обновление той страницы на которой находишься, а то на главную перекидывает

Comment: @steep, вам надо при переходах по страницам сохранять адрес и именно его перезагружать при обновлении

Comment: Да! Не долго я радовался. Я понимаю, что это очень сложно.

Comment: @steep, это совсем не сложно. Вам надо лишь отловить событие начала загрузки страницы и сохранить его в переменную класса. В onRefresh грузить значение этой переменной

Comment: Я же говорю, сложно. Не по зубам